# what are the advantages and disadvantages of using "xpath" in selenium?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am pretty new to selenium and the website I am testing is in HTML5 and there are no ID's on all the elements. SO, I have to find a unique pointer for all those elements I click. I found that Xpath could help a bit. But the website UI will be changing frequently. So, I want to know that what attribute could be a perfect alternative to **xpath** ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question's description and title are not the same. Any way try using CSS selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have advantage of using xpath, you will have to change it all the time, on every build. Just don't use it, make agreement with dev team to set ids on everything.

Comment: Thanks Sanja for the response

Answer (score 1):

If website Ui will be changing frequently don't use xpath. One line added will change all xpath you use. Request from the dev team to set id locators to all elements.

Answer (score 0):

Xpath reliability can be massively increased by using relative xpath rather than absolute.